# How do I compile nstat on Linux?

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, utility

I have to compile the nstat code in https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/main/misc/nstat.c but I think it cannot compile without ELF support and I checked the internet for ways that I can install them, but they're very confusing.

It would be so great if you could help me out.

for more context here's me trying to make the file:

```
root@mandy-VirtualBox:/home/mandy/iproute2# make

    lib
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
    
    ip
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
    
    tc
        YACC     emp_ematch.tab.c
    /bin/sh: 1: bison: not found
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:185: emp_ematch.tab.c] Error 127
    make: *** [Makefile:64: all] Error 2
```

and then here's my ./configure result:

```
root@mandy-VirtualBox:/home/mandy/iproute2# ./configure
TC schedulers
 ATM    no

libc has setns: yes
SELinux support: yes
ELF support: no
libmnl support: yes
Berkeley DB: yes
need for strlcpy: yes
libcap support: yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
/bin/sh: 1: bison: not found
```

You need to install `bison` on your computer.  There's probably a package by the same name available in your OS package manager.  If you need more specifics, tell us which Linux distribution you're using.

Comment: I installed bison like you said and then it said that flex was not found, so I had to install that, and then it worked!